# Numerical reconstruction of a scalar function from its gradient

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Consider a two-dimensional rectangular grid in the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ of the $xy-$plane. The grid consits of $N^2$ points. There is a scalar function $f$ of which we know that $f(0,0)=0$ and for each point $p=(x,y)$ of the rectangular grid, both $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)$ are known. What is the best (or some fairly good) way to proceed to numerically compute the scalar field $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Integrate first in the x-direction on the basis line, then in the y-direction. This has the disadvantage of not using half of the available information.

You can formulate this as a variational problem,
$$
\min_{f\in C^1:f(0)=0}\int_{rect}[(f_x-M)^2+(f_y-N)^2]d(x,y).
$$
The extremal condition is then
$$
\Delta f=f_{xx}+f_{yy}={\rm div}(M,N)=M_x+N_y 
$$
You can now discretize this equation directly or restrict the function class for the variational problem to functions composed of linear patches over triangle cells or bi-linear patches over rectangle cells.